# If a user cannot read excel file, can they view Excel Web Access?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My question is essentially the title.  I have a requirement to restrict people from viewing the base excel workbook due to potentially sensitive information.  However, I need to be able to display certain named parts from the workbook via and Excel Web Access web part.  Would a user without read permissions on the excel file be able to see the view specified by the web part, or do they need read access to view?

Comment: they need read access to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they do not have SP-read permissions to the .xlsx file, then EWA will not show it to them either.

The only idea I can think of is to make an extract of the "safe data" and show that in EWA.

Comment: That is a bummer.  That is what I was guessing, that we will just need to "scrub" the sensitive information (such as names). Thanks!